# Nonlinear least squares and regularization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, least-squares

Consider the nonlinear least-squares minimization of a vector of $n$ residuals $\mathbf{f}$ in $p$ parameters $\mathbf{x}$:
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) ||^2
$$
This can be done with a standard Gauss-Newton or Levenberg-Marquardt approach, using the $n \times p$ Jacobian matrix
$$
J_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}
$$
Now suppose I want to regularize the solution, so I want to solve
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) ||^2 + \lambda^2 x^T C x
$$
for some symmetric $p \times p$ matrix $C$. It seems to me there are two ways to proceed.

**Option 1**

If $C$ happens to be SPD, then we can do a Cholesky decomposition $C = U^T U$ where $U$ is upper triangular. Then we get
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) ||^2 + \lambda^2 || U \mathbf{x}||^2
$$
Here we can form the augmented residual vector and Jacobian:
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbf{f}} &= \pmatrix{ \mathbf{f} \\ \lambda U \mathbf{x}} \\
\tilde{J} &= \pmatrix{ J \\ \lambda U}
\end{align}
and the problem becomes
$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} || \tilde{\mathbf{f}}(\mathbf{x}) ||^2
$$
for which we can apply a standard Gauss-Newton or LM code to solve.
The augmented system will have $n + p$ residuals and a $(n+p) \times p$ Jacobian matrix. For a large number of parameters $p$ (say several thousand), this could add significant cost to the nonlinear iteration.

**Option 2**

Alternatively, suppose $C$ is symmetric but not positive definite, then we can't perform a Cholesky factorization. In this case we can still proceed by forming the augmented system:
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbf{f}} &= \pmatrix{ \mathbf{f} \\ \lambda \sqrt{x^T C x}} \\
\tilde{J} &= \pmatrix{ J \\ \lambda \frac{x^T C}{x^T C x}}
\end{align}
In this case, we now have $n + 1$ residuals and the Jacobian is $(n+1) \times p$.

**My question is whether Option 2 is superior to Option 1? Option 2 requires factoring a smaller Jacobian matrix which could result in significant speed improvements when $p$ is very large. However I wonder if Option 1 might converge faster to the solution, since more "information" is stored in the residual vector and Jacobian. Does anyone have any insights into this?**

For a long time I used Option 1, but recently I encountered a problem where $C$ is symmetric but not positive definite, so I am forced to consider Option 2. Just wondering if Option 2 might have worse convergence properties.

EDIT: it seems there is a third option which may or may not be useful:

**Option 3**

The minimization problem can be put in the form:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \tilde{\mathbf{f}}^T W \tilde{\mathbf{f}}
$$
where
$$
W = \pmatrix{ I & 0 \\ 0 & C}
$$
and
$$
\tilde{\mathbf{f}} = \pmatrix{ \mathbf{f} \\ \lambda x}
$$
In this form, it may not be possible to use an off-the-shelf LM software due to the $W$ matrix, but certainly a specialized algorithm could be developed to solve this problem. Again I am not clear if this offers any advantage over Option 1 or 2.

Comment: When you say that $C$ may not be positive definite, are you saying that it might be indefinite, or just positive semidefinite? (The former is much, much harder than the latter.)

Comment: It is positive semi-definite (eigenvalues are either 0 or positive)

Comment: So for my problem, the choice is between Option 2 and 3 - I cannot use Option 1 since the Cholesky factorization doesn't exist for my $C$.

Comment: Another option is to use the symmetric square root of your positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: I didn't consider that, thank you

Comment: The Cholesky factorization does exist, but square-root based routines can run into stability issues. Instead, you can also just compute the LDL decomposition and round all negative elements in D to zero.

Comment: That's what I would do: compute the $LDL^T$ decomposition. If you want to, you can then write $C=(D^{1/2}L^T)^T(D^{1/2}L^T)$, which is a product of a triangular matrix with itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that if there is a nonzero vector in the nullspace of $C$ and also in the null space of $f$, then your problem won't be effectively regularized.

Comment: In my application, $C$ is symmetric and banded, but it seems lapack doesn't have an LDL routine for those matrices :/

Comment: @Brian: do you mean the nullspace of $J$, not $f$?

Comment: @vibe Yes, sorry for the confusion.